# modify a dll using Visual Studios 2013 and dotPeek

Tags: dll, visual-studio-2013, dotpeek

I have a legacy dll file for which I do not have the original source code. I have used dotPeek 1.4.1 to open the dll and create a visual studios project. In this case, I am changing embedded e-mail addresses that have changed. My problem is that I can't seem to get Visual Studios 2013 to generate a new dll file once I make the changes. I am not sure that I am doing it correctly. I believe that if a build the solution, it should generate a new dll file in the bin\Debug folder. However, there is nothing in that folder. Any ideas how to generate the new dll and where it is located ?

Thank You,

Eric

Answer (score -1):

The main idea is not to use dotPeek for this. Use any ILEditor tools available.
http://sourceforge.net/projects/dile/ project is what you are looking for.

Alternatively is new e-mail and old e-mail addresses are same in size any hex editor will do the job.